# Shiny R: App stop working after deployment

Tags: r, shiny

I developed an app to do some analysis. Everything worked perfectly on my desktop, however, when I deployed it, the app stop working.

The app has some functions that I used, and I was able to find the one that is causing the trouble, which is this

```
samplisa=function(a,b,iterat=50)
{
  colm=c(grep("IniciarH",colnames(data)),grep("ResponderH",colnames(data)))
na=dim(a)[1]
nb=dim(b)[1]
r2=0
aa=numeric()
bb=numeric()
for(i in 1:iterat)
{
   if(na>nb)
   {
      lina=sort(sample(1:na,nb))
      lma=lm(a[lina,colm]~b[,colm])
      r2b=summary(lma)[[8]]
      if(r2b>r2)
      {
         aa=a[lina,colm];bb=b[,colm];r2=r2b
      }
   }
   else
   {
      lina=sort(sample(1:nb,na))
      lma=lm(a[,colm]~b[lina,colm])    ####Apparently this is causing problem
      r2b=summary(lma)[[8]]
      if(r2b>r2)
      {
         aa=a[,colm];bb=b[lina,colm];r2=r2b
      }
   }
}
 ret=data.frame(aa,bb,stringsAsFactors=FALSE);colnames(ret)=c("GABARITO","JUIZ")
ret
}
```

this function takes two data.frames a and b, and a numeric vector iterat. It actually only use a specific column of each data frames, which is a numeric data [objects of class POSIXct that I turned into numeric with as.numeric()].

The app returns
invalid type (list) for variable 'a[, colm]' [note line w/ the comment]

I try'd to unlist(), but it only returns me another error. As I mentioned, everything's working exactly as it should in my desktop.

I uploaded the whole app to a dropbox folder so it would be easier to get some help.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kka2p4zoinfdxrt/AAAc1cEl9z4F6ftEj5TA9Bo0a?dl=0

Thanks for any help. :)

PS: as suggested, I also submitted the app to my github as follows
https://github.com/RicardoFCJ/Calibragem

Comment: Just a blind shot. Have you tried `b[, colm, drop = FALSE]`? FWIW, it's easier to upload apps to GitHub because it's trivial to deploy them from there.

Comment: I guess you mean `a[,colm,drop=FALSE]`, since that's where I got the error message from. Anyway, just did it, and it did not worked.